# CORS issue while enable under attack mode in cloudfare

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

We facing the "CORS" Issue while enable Under Attack Mode, We are working on the dynamic Marketplace project using NodeJs (graphql,apollo-server) and ReactJs (graphql,apollo-client),we have placed Each server for Front and Back end separately , if Our Front end [ https://fronend.com ] attempts to serve resources from [ https://backend.com] "CROS" issue occurring only while the "Under-attack" mode is in on state,
if the Under-attack mode is in off state then everything is working Fine.

My Question is :

1. Is Cloud-fare Under-attack mode will Cause " CORS" Issue ...? if Yes , How can we overcome from this issue ?
2. Is Cloudfare restrict Request Headers..?  If yes , Please Guide us to proceed Further
   We tried all the techniques that flow on the internet and that was not work
   If anything else from Cloudfare causes this problem, let us know what the problem is and its solution.

Thanks in advance